# How to add a list of string in Redis?

Tags: redis, spring-data

I want to store a set of strings against a key in a Redis in a single step. Presently, I am using multi-exec mechanism for storing by iterating over the set.

I am using spring-data-redis library for Redis operation.

Is it possible to store a set of strings in a Redis in a single step ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `RPUSH`/`LPUSH` commands accept multiple values, beginning with Redis 2.4. Example:

```
LPUSH key value1 value2 value3
```

If you're using a set rather than a list, it's the `SADD` command:

```
SADD key value1 value2 value3
```

In Spring Data Redis, `StringRedisConnection` supports multiple values in the `rPush`, `lPush`, and `sAdd` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to store a list or a set? (You refer to both.)

In general you can store your list of strings as a single JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring data API for Redis , you can set a list or object using

eg:-

> opsForList.leftPush("key", object);